# Как рандомно выбрать координаты точки на местности в границах города?

Tags: android, google-maps-api, геолокация

Например я хочу выбрать 10 случайных точек в Москве. Как это сделать, чтобы точка была именно в городе а не где-то в области в лесу или в болоте.

Что если взять прямоугольник в котором полностью уместится Москва и рандомно брать координаты долготы и широты в нем?

Но тогда все равно зацепится область за городом.

Взять прямоугольник чтобы в нем уместилась часть города?

Как быть с зоной города, к ней не относящейся?

Взять произвольную фигуру по границе города? Это что вручную делать? И как же тогда брать рандом координаты в этой фигуре?

Может есть инструмент способный выдать 100500 точек города? Если есть поделитечь им. Не пойму как даже гуглить на эту тему...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы делал так

1. Построить полигон границ города
2. Найти в этом полигоне минимальную и максимальную широту и долготу
3. Сгенерировать случайную точку в получившимся описывающем прямоугольнике
4. Проверить принадлежит ли точка полигону. Если нет - то точку отбросить

Функций проверки на принадлежность полигону в инете навалом

Comment: Отличная идея, а полигон границ города вручную писать? Все координаты?

Comment: @СергейГрушин У гугла должен быть соответствующий метод

Comment: Блин не могу найти

Comment: @СергейГрушин Посмотрите вот https://habrahabr.ru/post/253515/ и вот https://forum.openstreetmap.org/viewtopic.php?id=29018

Comment: @СергейГрушин Вот здесь https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/9OTkWOM5tBw говорят, что импоссибл